# Crontab for an rsync backup with ssh connection

Tags: cron, rsync

UBUNTU 16.04 Root Server.

I would like to have a crontab job run an rsync backup job every night at 2:14am.
It copies a "folder" from an Ubuntu 16.04 machine to another root server in the internet.
There is an ssh connection possible with a ssh key login.

The following command works in the terminal:

> /usr/bin/rsync -az --delete -e ssh /home/user/folder/ user@server.example.com:/home/user/folder

But the following crontab job does not work:

> 14 2 * * * /usr/bin/rsync -az --delete -e ssh /home/user/folder/ user@server.example.com:/home/user/folder

I am having a hard time with crontab to be honest. It always feels to be a lucky situation if the job actually works.

Can someone see from the crontab job above what I am doing wrong?

greetings, Chris

Comment: What error does the command give when running from cron? 'does not work' is not enough.

Comment: I agree that this is not enough. But where could I see what error it gives? I have no idea where to see the error message, since it'sa a cronjob. And that runs "in the background" (if it runs).

Comment: redirect the output from the command with `> /path/to/outfile 2>&1` and check the content of the file after cron has run the job.

Comment: Thanks for that already!. I get the error message: Host key verification failed.
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.1]

Comment: I guess the Host Key error happens because it tries to connect as "root" and not as "user". I need to define the ssh user for the connection.

Comment: This is a strange behaviour for me since the host key verification works when I use the command on the terminal. And the user that should access (user@server.example.com) is defined in the command line. WOuld you see what is going woring here?

Comment: I am not sure what it means. Does the rsync work without `-e ssh` - on commandline, and in cron ? It could be some kind of ssh PTY allocation error.

Comment: I got it to run (see solution). Thanks for your help, Soren. Logging the job pointed me into the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I had was that the ssh connection 
The Host Key verification failed.

I ran the cronjob on the crontab of root. 
(I added the cronjob via "sudo crontab -e".)

> 14 2 * * * /usr/bin/rsync -az --delete -e ssh /home/user/folder/ user@server.example.com:/home/user/folder

It seems that the ssh connection then is established by the root user and not by the "user".

So the connection attempt is actually:

> ssh root@server.example.com

and not

> ssh user@server.example.com

So I added the cronjob to the crontab of the "user".
(crontab -e (without sudo)).

Now the Host Key Verification works and the crontab rsync job is executed properly.

I don't know exactly if the above assumptions are correct but this solved the problem.

I hope this thread will help someone else at some stage as well.

Greetings, Chris

Answer (score 0):

In addittion to run crontab -e as the user yo are using,  you have to create a public key without passphrase.